# CodeIgniter Pagination is not working

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I set the CodeIgniter pagination's attributes but I am getting an error.

```
1 2 3 4 5 >
```

My pagination is working on pages 2-5 except page number 1. I do not realizing why it's happening. Here is my controller function where controller name is `c_forum`.

```
function show_posts_by_chapter($id_chapter=false) {
    if($id_chapter==false)
        show_404();


    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/c_forum/show_posts_by_chapter/" . $id_chapter.'/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->m_forum->num_rows_by_chapter($id_chapter);

    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $configp['uri_segment'] = 4;

    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

    $data['chapter_id'] = $id_chapter;
    $data['allowed'] = $this->_get_level();
    $data['count_rows'] = $config['total_rows'];


    $data['posts_all'] = $this->m_forum->get_posts_by_chapter($config['per_page'], $page, $id_chapter);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('forum/show_posts', $data);
}
```

View is simple  :

```
 `<?php echo $links; ?>`
```

Got answe: I used `$configp['uri_segment'] = 4;` and it should be `$config['uri_segment'] = 4;`

Comment: What do you mean by "no underline under 1"?

Comment: i wanted to upload a picture , then u may get it easily.But new here . But main theme is  if i hit next after 5 i am getting 2 not 1 .

Comment: It's probably `$config["num_links"]`, what happens if you remove that?

Comment: same  result after removing $config["num_links"] , now getting 1 2 3 > last instead of previous one , but still 1 is not got.

Answer (score 0):

**$configp['uri_segment'] = 4;**
This should be
 
 **$config['uri_segment'] = 4;**